# Buffering to the hard disk

Tags: c++, windows, buffer, pipe

I am receiving a large quantity of data at a fixed rate. I need to do some processing on this data on a different thread, but this may run slower than the data is coming in, so I need to buffer the data. Due to the quantity of data coming in the available RAM would be quickly exhausted, so it needs to overflow onto the hard disk. What I could do with is something like a filesystem-backed pipe, so the writer could be blocked by the filesystem, but not by the reader running too slowly.

Here's a rough set of requirements:

- Writing should not be blocked by the reader running too slowly.
- If data is read slow enough that the available RAM is exhausted it should overflow to the filesystem. It's ok for writes to the disk to block.
- Reading should block if no data is available unless the stream has been closed by the writer.
- If the reader is able to keep up with the data then it should never hit the hard disk as the RAM buffer would be sufficient (nice but not essential).
- Disk space should be recovered as the data is consumed (or soon after).

Does such a mechanism exist in Windows?

Comment: Try writing your program without hd buffering and see if it works well already with Windows memory manager.

Comment: With the amount of data we are receiving we will simply run out of space too quickly for that to work. We will also run out of address space since we're stuck on a 32-bit machine..

Comment: Try Windows File Mapping. Its pretty good at managing data swaps from ram to hdd here is the msdn site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The problem with a file mapping is that it has a fixed size.  However, you could probably work around this by creating new file mappings as necessary on the fly.  You would need to make sure you create each new mapping far enough in advance to be ready for you when you need it, you might want a separate thread for this.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic message queue. Did you consider MSMQ or similar? MSMQ has all the properties you are asking for. You may want to use direct addressing to avoid Active Directory http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700996(v=vs.85).aspx and use local or TCP/IP queue address.

Answer (score 0):

Use an actual file. Write to the file as the data is received, and in another process read the data from the file and process it.

You even get the added benefits of no multithreading.